How to disable IAsyncEnumerable Buffering in ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API?
I have the following API endpoint:
[HttpGet("test")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetStrings()
{
    Random rnd = new();

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        yield return rnd.Next(100) ;
    }
}

What I expect is to get a stream of numbers every 500ms, but this is not happening, instead it returns to the client after 5 seconds with the whole payload.
So, how to make this code stream these numbers? I use .NET 8.0.

possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876817/clarification-on-how-iasyncenumerable-works-with-asp-net-web-api

There's no IAsyncEnumerable buffering. The HTTP protocol itself has no streaming responses, that's what gRPC or WebSockets are for. It seems you're trying to make ASP.NET Core return one JSON document per newline as a "streaming" response. ASP.NET Core itself sends responses in chunks though because writing individual bytes to a network stream would be far too slow. The code tries to write just 4 bytes at a time for a total of 400. The data is probably too little to be sent immediatelly

Are you using System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json ?

@nsevens yes it was working before as shown in this answer

@EnricoMassone i use  System.Text.Json

@PanagiotisKanavos I test similar code in past it was sending the partial JSON as shown in this answer .... actually my real code is constructing a bunch of objects each object will take few second to be constructed I just want to return the data as son as they constructed and don't wait till the whole data to be finished

Also likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78539613/blazor-webassembly-streaming-and-ui-update

@PanagiotisKanavos, just a question from my side. Based on my understanding HTTP is able to perform chunked transfer encoding, to send data to the client as soon as data is available instead of waiting for the entire response content to be generated. Is my understanding correct ? I'm just talking at the protocol level, forget about the ASP.NET core behavior for a moment.


So, how to make this code stream these numbers? I use .NET 8.0.

This is related with how you send the request. According to the article, it said When using System.Text.Json formatter, MVC relies on the support that System.Text.Json added to stream the result..
If your application use the right package System.Text.Json and make sure the response header is the application/json. Then you will get a stream of numbers every 500ms.
You could check it by using the F12 development's network tab.
The reason why you found it just show all the numbers is according to your browser feature, but inside the network tab it's a steam of numbers.
Result:



So, basically IAsyncEnumerable with System.Text.Json streams the response to the client as expected ?

Yes, you are right.
